# Unity Tank turret rotation with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a tank game in unity and I want to rotate tank's turret with mouse.
The main Camera is a child of the turret.

I've tried this:

```
Ray dir = MainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(dir, out hit)){}
Turret.transform.LookAt(hit.point);
```

But the turret starts to rotate infinitely.
I think it's because of MainCamera is a child of Turret.
So I don't know how to do this.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why can't you move camera from turret childen to some other object? 
And by the way, maybe you need to move `Turret.transform.LookAt(hit.point);` inside `{}`

Comment: Hello, I want to make camera follow the turret, so player can see where he aims.

Comment: So you just need smooth rotation?

Comment: I think yes. Do you know how to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the angle between mouse and turret and rotate it with quaternion.lookat

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Camera _camera;

    [SerializeField] private float _rotationFactor = 0.01f;

    private Transform _cameraTransform;
    
    void Start()
    {
        _cameraTransform = _camera.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var screenCenter = new Vector3(Screen.width / 2.0f, Screen.height / 2.0f);
        // This prevents camera rotation when mouse is in 100 pixels circle in screen center.
        if (!(Input.mousePosition - screenCenter).magnitude < 100f) 
            return;
        
        var mouseWorldPos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + Vector3.forward);
        Debug.Log(mouseWorldPos);
        _camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
            _camera.transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(mouseWorldPos - _cameraTransform.position),
            _rotationFactor);
    }
}
```